# c#. Как реализовать ожидание выполнения функции?

Tags: c#

Имеется такой цикл с подпиской на событие:

```
            int nach = Convert.ToInt32(strNtext.Text);
        int konech = Convert.ToInt32(strAlltext.Text);
    for (int i = nach; i <= konech; i++)
    {
        //Excel.Range rng2 = sheet.Range["B4"];
        //Excel.Range rng3 = sheet.Range["C4"];
        richTextBox1.AppendText("Загружаем страницу");
        string urlo = "http://localhost:888/i.html";
        webBrowser1.Navigate(urlo);
        result = strestext.Text + i.ToString();
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);          
    }
```

В событии слушается клик по элементу и внесении в Excel. Но сейчас нет ожидания выполнения этого события.
Тоесть алгоритм должен быть такой.
i=1 => ждём клика и занесение в excel из события => i++ и заново с i=2 и.т.д

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Абстрагируясь от вопроса, зачем это вообще вам надо, я покажу пример асинхронного ожидания события

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    WebBrowser _wb;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Width = 500;
        this.Height = 500;
        _wb = new WebBrowser() { Width = 500, Height = 500 };
        this.Controls.Add(_wb);
        LoadAndClick();
    }

    private async void LoadAndClick()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var uri = $"https://google.ru?{i}";

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler docCompleted = null;

            docCompleted = (s, e) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    // отписываемся
                    this._wb.DocumentCompleted -= docCompleted;

                    // тут какой то полезный код
                }
                finally
                {
                    // отмечаем, что событие отработало. 
                    tcs.TrySetResult(0);
                }

            };
            this._wb.DocumentCompleted += docCompleted;
            _wb.Navigate(uri);

            await tcs.Task; // ждем, когда событие сработает. 

            Debug.WriteLine($"{uri} processed");
        }
    }
}
```

В примере мы грузим странички одну за другой. Причем следующая загрузка начнется только после того, как предыдущая закончится.

Comment: Спасибо! А для async await какая сборка идет?

Comment: @technor что значит сборка? Вы какой версии фреймворк используете?

Comment: 4.0, выше нужен? Ошибки: Заранее определяемый тип "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IAsyncStateMachine" не определен или не импортирован (CS0518) и Не удается найти все типы, требуемые модификатором "async". Возможно, указана неправильная версия .NET Framework или отсутствует ссылка на необходимую сборку. (CS1993) - C:\Users\n3400-00-306\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\av_export\av_export\MainForm.cs:82,13

Comment: Уже увидел что 4.5 минимум) Спасибо! Хорошего дня!

Comment: @technor тогда да, вам [нужен доп пакет](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19421907/312041) и минимум 2012 студия. Хотя лучше всего конечно пользоваться самыми современными инструментами.

Comment: Добрый день! А можно еще вопрос по теме? Как бы в эту конструкцию еще внедрить ожидание события Document.Click? Тоесть ожидается загрузка страницы, затем ожидается клик с выполнением кода и затем переходим на i=2 и там до конца i

Comment: @technor точно также только хандлер `WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler docCompleted` будет другого типа (чтобы понять какого, смотрите ваше событие)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77976/discussion-between-technor-and-tym32167).

Comment: @technor в чат не имею возможности, он у меня забанен фаерволом

Comment: Я вообще случайно открыл) Извиняюсь) Что-то я неправильно все таки делаю... Мой код: https://pastebin.com/3tsm8tgL  Запускается раз через чаз, причем билд проходит, только форма начинает открываться и валится с ошибкой: "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Адресат вызова создал исключение. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."
И ссылается на webBrowser1.Document.Click += docCompleted;

Comment: @technor пастебины для меня тоже закрыты. Скопируйте мой код и запустите. Если он у вас нормально отработает, то значит вы что то не так делаете у себя в коде.

Answer (score 0):

Архитектурная схема не очень, разумнее всю логику унести в событие webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted, или использовать переменную в виде флага выставляемого из webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted и по ней продолжать обработку, но это не красиво.
Использовать эвенты? Как архитектуру логики.

и судя по `string urlo` грузиться в цикле будет одна страница, но много раз :)